# How to get all unique values of XML elements using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML file.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.com');
```

It looks something like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#1635 ▼
  +"@attributes": array:1 [▶]
  +"shop": SimpleXMLElement {#1615 ▼
    +"categories": SimpleXMLElement {#1616 ▶}
    +"currencies": SimpleXMLElement {#1617 ▶}
    +"offers": SimpleXMLElement {#1618 ▼
      +"offer": array:1513 [▼
        0 => SimpleXMLElement {#1657 ▶}
        1 => SimpleXMLElement {#1658 ▶}
        2 => SimpleXMLElement {#1659 ▶}
        3 => SimpleXMLElement {#1660 ▶}
        ...
        120158 => SimpleXMLElement {#3169 …10}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need all the elements of the offer.
In this way I select the path to the elements I need:

`$xml = $xml->shop->offers->offer;`

And I get this:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#995 ▼
  +"@attributes": array:2 [▼
    "id" => "552550582"
    "available" => "true"
  ]
  +"categoryId": "3e71f0c49b"
  +"description": """
    text
    """
  +"modified_time": "1697969563"
  +"name": "Long-sleeve shirt"
  +"param": array:3 [▼
    0 => SimpleXMLElement {#1617 ▶}
    1 => SimpleXMLElement {#1618 ▼
      +"@attributes": array:1 [▼
        "name" => "gender"
      ]
      +"0": "female"
    }
    2 => SimpleXMLElement {#1619 ▼
      +"@attributes": array:1 [▼
        "name" => "color"
      ]
      +"0": "Black"
    }
  ]
  +"picture": array:8 [▶]
  +"price": "6490.0"
  +"url": "example.com ▶"
}
```

How can I get all possible elements from each offer and its only unique values. I want to see it something like this:

```
$offerValues = [
   'categoryId' = [1,2,3,10...],
   'param@gender' = ['female', 'male'],
   'param@color' = ['black', 'white', 'red'],
   ...
]
```

I'm just starting to learn CML and would appreciate any help!

Comment: `$xml->shop->offers->offer` is an array; Can you add code you are using?

Comment: @user3783243, So I provided it. I'm getting the first SimpleXMLElement element. You can add an array element number to select the desired element ($xml->shop->offers->offer[1])

Comment: I think I found something suitable.```$color = $xml->xpath('//shop/offers/offer/param[@name = "color"]');```This way I get all the elements I need. But now I'm explicitly pointing specifically at the element. And it is necessary in a loop automatically. And secondly, I don’t need all the values, but I need unique ones.

Comment: If `$xml->shop->offers->offer` is an array (which it sounds like it is)  `foreach($xml->shop->offers->offer as $offer`) should allow iterating over every offer. Question details are too vague for me to give definitive answer.

Comment: You input is json not xml.  So use a json parser instead of an xml parser.

Comment: @jdweng: where do you see json as input?

Comment: XML tags are angle brackets.  JSON has square brackets and curly brackets.  SimpleXMLElement is json.

Comment: @jdweng That is diagnostic information from SimpleXML library. The data structure is XML, not JSON. ( We don't have the real information in question, `$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.com');` loaded XML, `<xml>....</xml>` then created `SimpleXMLElement`s). The user has provided `var_dump` output of that element here which is JSON formatted.

Comment: It’s strange, someone disliked my question)) Although I asked it correctly. Well, okay. I seem to have completed the task. Maybe someone will need it. ```$color = $xml->xpath('//shop/offers/offer/param[@name = "color"][not(. = following::param[@name = "color"]/.)]');```

Comment: @user3783243 : The OP clearly says "It looks something like this" over the json code.

Comment: @jdweng OP also clearly states `I have an XML file.` and then shows the PHP code they use to load the XML into the library. They then are showing the output of the PHP library. Simple example `var_dump(new simplexmlelement('<xml><a>test</a></xml>'))`.. So critique the OP for too minimal an example. ...(and for someone familiar with PHP and simplexml maybe that is usable. I'm not going to make guesses about what the XML has in it from the diagnostic data)

Answer (score 0):

`$color = $xml->xpath('//shop/offers/offer/param[@name = "color"][not(. = following::param[@name = "color"]/.)]');`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly edit your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?